# Change picture and background on click

Tags: jquery, background, click, image

I have a little problem with my test-site i'm making.

I love experimenting with Javascript but i'm getting stuck on this little code...

**What i'm trying to reach:**

*When you click on a picture below, the picture will become visible in the main of the page, and also in the background. When you click in the main of the page ( where the picture is visible ), it will automaticly go to the next one.*

**What I have right now:**

*I already made a popup window, and now starting the pictures. I already inserted a code, but it don't seem to open very well. I tried alot but it's still not working.*

**jQuery**

*What I have tried to do is:*

```
$('#photo').fadeIn();
$("#gallery ul li").on("click", function() {
var selector = '#photo[src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]';

$(".selected").hide();

$('selector').fadeIn();
return false;
});

$('#gallery ul li').on('click', function() {
$("#photo").hide();
var next = $(this).next();
if (next.length > 0) {
    next.fadeIn();    
} else {
    $('.selected').fadeIn();
}
return false;
});
```

Also I have made a **jsFiddle** where I have input the HTML & CSS.

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yahitchu/GWtHN/)

Answer (score 2):

`$('selector').fadeIn();` is looking for an HTML tag called "selector". There is no such tag.

To use the variable you defined, lose the quotes.

```
$(selector).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Hello Diodeus, Thankyou for your answer.

I tried changing it in my jQuery, but it doesn't seem to change something... Maybe i'm just using the wrong javascript?

Comment: I don't know, but using an HREF-based selector is probably the issue. You should look into using relative selectors, such as prev() and next() to target your image.

Comment: Hmm, Well i'm pretty new to jQuery and Javascript, and don't realy know how to do that... Is it actually possible to create the 'thing' I want?

Comment: There are many jQuery scripts that already do this. Go shopping. :)

Comment: I am already looking for the jQuery script for more then a day haha, can you maybe give me a little push to the right direction? I don't even know where to search ( well, I tried google and tried almost every code I found, but doesn't even seem to do something... )

I'm realy sorry, i'm new to javascript and trying to understand it, I jumped a hole in the air when I made the pop-up message in the upper-right haha. :) , Thanks alot for actually putting time into this, I realy appreciate it!